# Изменение даты в Java для Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Задача заключается в том, чтобы на основе текущей даты сформировать новую и перевести ее в unix-формат. А конкретно выставить следующий день, часы установить на 20, минуты и секунды на 00.

попытка:

```
Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm");
        String [] values=dateFormat.format(date).toString().split("/");
        values[0]+=1;
        values[3]="20";
        values[4]="00";
        String publish_date=new String();
        for (String str:values)
        {
            publish_date= publish_date+str+"/";
        }
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(publish_date);
            publish_date=Long.toString(date.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Приведите, пж-та, код текстом, не картинкой. Они не индексируются поисковиками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием `LocalDateTime` все очень просто:

```
LocalDateTime tommorow = LocalDateTime.now()
             .plusDays(1)
             .withHour(20)
             .withMinute(0)
             .withSecond(0)
             .withNano(0);

long seconds = tommorow.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond();
```

---

С использованием класса `Calendar`:

```
Calendar tommorow = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
tommorow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
tommorow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
tommorow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
tommorow.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
tommorow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Long.toString(tommorow.getTime().getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: AndroidStudio не знает о такой библиотеке, не понимаю, нужно зависимость в gradle добавлять или в чем проблема

Comment: Это java8 DateTime API, тогда уточните какую версию java используете вы.

Comment: Кажется была не обновлена java, сейчас проверю